# How to send integer values in Servlet through selectbox

Tags: java, servlets

i have a selectBox which contains values from 1 to 10 i am sending the values to a Servlet to do some calculations.But it is coming to the Servlet as String aslo the Integer.parseInt() not working  here is my code

```
 <form action="LinkServlet">                    
                <center><select name="connections" size="3" style="background-color: bisque;">
                        <option>-- Select--</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2>2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Show"/>

                </center>
            </form>
```

i am getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: null is error  and in Servlet i am catching the value as

```
        int No_of_Conn =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("connections"));
```

Comment: Subho Check my answer .You have made a mistake in your `select`

Comment: Also try to use firebug in such cases .It will help you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<option value="2>2</option>` is wrong make it `<option value="2">2</option>`

[image]

See when i changed to `<option value="2">2</option>` this i am getitng the parameter value from UI .See in firebug console .Also in the servlet `doPost` `System.out.println(request.getParameter("connections"));` is printing 2

Comment: but is this 2 String or integer

Comment: @Subho  when it will come from UI .It will be String you have to use `Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("connections"))`

Comment: @Subho is the solution Working ?

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving null in `request.getParameter("connections")` probably

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible things that are happening with your code:

1. If you do not select any value, null is going to be the value obtained in the Servlet when you do a `request.getParameter("connections")`
2. If you select the first value i.e. --Select--, that is not a number. Hence if you try a Integet.parseInt on that, it gives the exception.

So in both the above cases, since the value is either null or not a number, you are getting the exception. In all other cases, if you select a value between 1 or 10, it will work fine.

You have 2 choices:

1. Do a JavaScript validation on the client, so that the incorrect values do not get passed to the server.
2. Additionally, I also suggest to keep a check on the Servlet side so that you do not move forward with any parsing or code logic, till the input values are not what you expect.

Comment: i have to do the application is that manner that when i do not select anything an output will be shown and if i select a value from 1 to 10 then an output will come. can you help from here?

Comment: @Subho I suggest you choose a value which will be selected by default if use has not selected anything. eg `<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>`

Comment: If you want to do all those checks on the Server, that is fine. Simple put a `try ... catch` around your parseInt code, if there is an exception, you can return an error code/message, otherwise you can do what your normal processing has to do.